# Need to be able to sftp to iSeries and write to a Library structure

Tags: linux, sftp, ibm-midrange

I have created a script to move files from a Linux source to a lib folder on an iseries server - part of the script connects to the iseries server:

```
   sftp -oIdentityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa my_user@server.mydomain.com <<EOF
                cd /qsys.lib/folder.lib
                put *.txt
                exit
EOF
```

In the script (on Linux source server), I able to sftp to an iseries server fine - once on, I can cd to the /qsys.lib/user.lib folder. Unfortunately, not able to put anything on this library folder once connected?

So question is, is this possible to write (put) files to this destination using sftp with additional commands in the script to allow this?

Comment: "Unfortunately, not able to put anything on this library folder once connected" Your script contains a "put" command. What happens when you invoke your script? Do you get any error messages? What do the errors say?

Comment: Your script sets the remote path to `/qsys.lib/folder.lib`, but your question says you want the remote path to be `/qsys.lib/user.lib`  Which is correct?

Comment: Yeah, due to this being one of many scripts that are each unique, I just used default naming. I meant to write /qsys.lib/folder.lib. The error message, after it says it has successfully connected, is ‘Bad Message’

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/q/641053/115396

Answer (score 1):

Path names in the `QSYS.LIB` file system have to respect some [restrictions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=lqfs-path-names)

If you want to put a file name `a.txt` in a source file name `MYFILE` in a library named `MYLIB` for example you have to put it in some path like `/qsys.lib/mylib.lib/myfile.file/a.mbr`